# MVC3 - Post files via AJAX & JSON without a form

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, json

I have an Action Method that receives a complex JSON object from the client. I serialize this object on the client side and because of the complexity, I can't (don't want to) use a form submit to post the data.

I also need to be able to send files along with this ajax request. My action method works perfectly and binds the JSON object (actually List of objects) just fine using jQuery.ajax(). When I move to the [ajax form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) so that I can send files the object binding breaks. I attempt to submit the form with the plugin and send my object along as additional data. The action method no longer sees my object.

Any thoughts on how to post JSON and files together to the same action method?

Here's the jQuery.ajax() method that works. No form submit here, this is just sending JSON data to the server

```
$.ajax({
            url: "/Controller/Create2",
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(model),
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json, charset=utf-8',
            beforeSend: function () {

            },
            success: function (data) {

            },
            error: function () {


            }
        });
```

My Action method takes a List of objects perfectly this way.

```
public ActionResult Create2(List<CreateModel> model)
{
       //Do stuff

}
```

But when I do an ajax submit on the form and append the data, the model comes back null.

```
f.ajaxSubmit({
            url: "/Controller/Create2",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(model),
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json, charset=utf-8',
            beforeSend: function () {

            },
            success: function (data) {

            },
            error: function (data) {

            }
        });
```

I need to retain the functionality of binding to JSON objects in the Action Method, does that mean I have to give up posting files?

Comment: Where is the file you are trying to post in the second method?

Comment: the file is part of the form (f). Sorry that wasn't clear. The ajaxSubmit plugin (I linked it above) takes care of posting the files via the hidden iFrame technique

Comment: As long as it's a plugin, how about you look into it's source code in the .js you presumably imported, see how it's serializing/posting the file, and extract just that part of it into your own method on the client side. Then use your first AJAX method that works, post your serialized model, along with a file serialized the way the plugin does it, and then add a second parameter to your Action method.

Comment: From where/how are you getting this `model` javascript variable that you are trying to JSON stringify? Are you building it manually? If yes, where does the data come from? Can the user modify the data contained in this variable through some UI? If yes, probably they should directly be part of the form you are submitting. If not, they could also be part of the form you are submitting but as hidden fields or even better as a single hidden field containing an id allowing you to refetch those values on the server from wherever they came initially.

Comment: The form is dynamic. The user can add and remove many different fields and can also submit multiple objects with a different number of custom fields. My first version of this tried to index and keep track of all of this via html attributes but it was just too much. It's much cleaner to allow the user to do all of their work and then serialize the object when they try to submit.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at jQXB ( http://www.jqxb.altervista.org or http://jqxb.codeplex.com )

Comment: You should mention what these two programs do and why they are relevant.